# Creating Incremented Values for a Hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I am new to perl and I'm trying to create a hash based on some user input. I want the keys of the hash to be between a specific range with an increment of each key. At this point I need the values of each key to be 0.

At the minute, my code is:

```
my %hash;
foreach (my $increm = $lowerbound; $increm <= $upperbound; ++$binsize) {

        push ($hash {$increm}, 0);

}
```

Example values could be:

```
$lowerbound = 500
$upperbound = 600
$binsize = 1
```

I get an error of "Not an ARRAY reference", what is the problem and where am I going wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all,

```
++$binsize
```

should be

```
$increm += $binsize;
```

---

`push` has two syntax:

```
 push @array, LIST
 push $array_ref, LIST
```

You're using the second, which expects a reference to an array, but you're passing undef instead. Fix:

```
push $hash{$increm} ||= [], 0;
```

would do the trick. That said, that syntax is "highly experimental" and doesn't work with all reference to arrays. I suggest you stick to the traditional syntax.

```
push @{ $hash{$increm} ||= [] }, 0;
```

But thanks to autovivification, that simplifies to

```
push @{ $hash{$increm} }, 0;
```

---

But why are you using `push` at all? You only ever assign one value per key, so the `push` is equivalent to the following:

```
$hash{$increm} = [ 0 ];
```

---

Actually, it's questionable whether you want `$hash{$increm}` to be an array reference at all. Do you simply want the following?

```
$hash{$increm} = 0;
```

Comment: @Suic, Looks like he's trying to create a sparse array, in which case a hash is appropriate. e.g. Consider `$binsize = 1000;`

Comment: @Suic, that said, he might still actually want an array keyed by `int($i/$binsize)`.

Comment: I think you were right, $hash{$increm} = 0; was what I needed, however, when I go to print my keys the program crashes. How can I check that the hash has been created sucessfully?

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print(Dumper(\%hash));`

Comment: Thanks, but my program crashes when I try this. Any idea as to why this might be? The aim is to finally export the finished hash as a CSV, so printing isn't too important at this stage.

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is on line 42.

Answer (score 0):

You push onto arrays. Just use a simple assignment like this

```
$hash{$increment} = 0 ;
```

Also, don't leave a space between the end of $hash and the curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

You may do so:

`perl -MData::Dumper -e 'for (1..5) { $a->{$_} = 0 }; print Dumper $a'`

```
$VAR1 = {
          '4' => 0,
          '1' => 0,
          '3' => 0,
          '2' => 0,
          '5' => 0
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Push is for array, you can do it like this :

```
my %hash;

my $lowerbound = 500;
my $upperbound = 600;
my $binsize = 1;

foreach (my $increm = $lowerbound; $increm <= $upperbound; $binsize++) {
    $hash{$increm} = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but the program crashes when I go to print the keys using "print "$_\n" for keys %hash;"?